# Is there a way to replace an entire object from a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I have a date frame that I need to switch out values from it, like "BOX TRUCK" to just "TRUCK". I have tried to use the str.replace function but unfortunately it only changes the value of "TRUCK" in "BOX TRUCK" to "TRUCK" so I am left with the same issue. I need to be able to change multiple different values "BOX TRUck, FIRE TRUCK, Dumpster truck, etc." and so I have tried to look for "truck" and change them but it has not been working.

```
dft['VEHICLE_TYPE']  = dft['VEHICLE_TYPE'].str.replace(r'truck', 'TRUCK', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Something like `dft['VEHICLE_TYPE']  = dft['VEHICLE_TYPE'].str.upper().str.extract('(TRUCK)')`?

Comment: You can try changing your regex to `r'.*truck.*'`... but really we can't help you without far more details about what your data *actually* looks like.

Comment: Changing the regex worked perfectly thank you @BeRT2me I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be using a mask with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) instead of `str.replace`.

Also, rather than using an apply, use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
mask = dft['VEHICLE_TYPE'].str.contains('truck', case=False)
dft['VEHICLE_TYPE'] = dft['VEHICLE_TYPE'].mask(mask, 'TRUCK')
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that OP has a dataframe like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=['Count', 'Vehicle_type'])
df['Vehicle_type'] = np.random.choice(['BOX TRUCK', 'FIRE TRUCK', 'Dumpster truck'], p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2], size=10)


[Out]:
   Count    Vehicle_type
0     35       BOX TRUCK
1     30  Dumpster truck
2     34      FIRE TRUCK
3     69       BOX TRUCK
4     13       BOX TRUCK
5     70       BOX TRUCK
6     53      FIRE TRUCK
7     56  Dumpster truck
8     43  Dumpster truck
9     40       BOX TRUCK
```

Assuming that the goal is to change to `TRUCK` anytime the value is `BOX TRUCK`, `FIRE TRUCK`, or, `Dumpster truck`, then the following will do the work

```
df['Vehicle_type'] = df['Vehicle_type'].apply(lambda x: 'TRUCK' if x.lower() in ['box truck', 'fire truck', 'dumpster truck'] else x)


   Count Vehicle_type
0     79        TRUCK
1     74        TRUCK
2     25        TRUCK
3     38        TRUCK
4     24        TRUCK
5     45        TRUCK
6     83        TRUCK
7     20        TRUCK
8     63        TRUCK
9     49        TRUCK
```

**Notes:**

- One is using `x.lower()` to be able to ignore case.
- If the column has additional categories/vehicle types that one wants to consider for the change, one can just add them to the list in the lambda function (write them with lower case).

An alternative, that doesn't require one to know the types that exist, as longs as it contains the string `truck` is using `str.contains`, as follows

```
df['Vehicle_type'] = df['Vehicle_type'].apply(lambda x: 'TRUCK' if x.lower().str.contains('truck') else x)
```

Or with `str.replace`, such as

```
df['Vehicle_type'] = df['Vehicle_type'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().str.replace('truck', 'TRUCK'))
```

---

If, on another hand, the goal is to replace, from the column `Vehicle_type`, `BOX TRUCK` to `Regular Truck` (the same logic can be applied to other changes), the following will do the work

```
df['Vehicle_type'] = df['Vehicle_type'].replace('BOX TRUCK', 'Regular Truck')

[Out]:
   Count    Vehicle_type
0     35   Regular Truck
1     30  Dumpster truck
2     34      FIRE TRUCK
3     69   Regular Truck
4     13   Regular Truck
5     70   Regular Truck
6     53      FIRE TRUCK
7     56  Dumpster truck
8     43  Dumpster truck
9     40   Regular Truck
```

Comment: You should use [pd.Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) instead of your custom apply functions~

Comment: @BeRT2me why is that?

Comment: Note that I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/7109869), but, given OP's requirements, it still doesn't answer my question.